# Is it confusing to link to another section of a site for more info?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, portfolio, blog

I want to create a portfolio site for my team. I have two goals: 1. Create a section to showcase our projects 2. Have a blog where we can provide updates and talk about the "behind the scenes" of our projects.

Here is my question:
If someone lands in the project section and sees a project, would it be confusing to also have articles in the blog talking about the same project? Is that redundant? Would a user expect to see ALL information for a project in one place?

Or...am I doing too much with the blog? Should blogs on sites like this be reserved for updates only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would harness the power of blog posts to draw in people interested in the process because either they are potential clients or people working in the field that want to see how others work.

My suggestion would be to first make a compelling showcase of a project and add the link to the blog in a manner that does not suggest that the user needs to also read a blog post to get the full picture. ( So don`t use a Read More but more of How Agile made our work easier for client X )

That way you help users that want to see more details and avoid redirecting users to a wall of text that they do no care about.